# When approve the record from apex - I get INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: apex, error, approval-process, process

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest singleApprovalProcess = new 
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
singleApprovalProcess.setComments('Reason here.');
singleApprovalProcess.setAction('Approve');
singleApprovalProcess.setWorkitemId(recordId);
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(singleApprovalProcess);
```

I am trying to approve the record from apex and getting the following error:

INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: [].

this error does not occur when I approve the record through the UI.

I am running the code as a Sys Admin

Comment: Even a sys admin needs to be granted access to objects and fields - something they can do for themselves, of course. Also, if they do not have the view or modify all data permissions then record sharing can still apply to them. Double check your setup and perhaps also read [this](https://www.salto.io/blog-posts/invalid-cross-reference-id).

Comment: @PhilW but this error does not occur when I approve the record through the UI.